# ProGuard fails with android.widget.Space

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

I'm having a problem when trying to build for a minified variant. ProGuard complains about `android.widget.Space`. The configuration is nothing special:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn afu.org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.androidplot.** { *; }
-keep class com.woxthebox.draglistview.** { *; }
-keep class com.jakewharton.threetenabp.** { *; }
-keep class me.srodrigo.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.retrofit2.** { *; }
```

So far I've tried adding

```
-keep class android.widget.Space
```

as the warning suggests but throws the same error. Also tried

```
-dontwarn android.widget.Space
```

with same results. The most significant change we did since our last successful build was switching from old Android Support Library to AndroidX. The error/warning we're getting is:

> Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'android.widget.Space' to keep library class 'android.widget.Space'
>   Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'android.widget.Space' to keep library class 'android.widget.Space'
>   Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
>         You should check your configuration for typos.
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
>   Note: there were 1 references to unknown class members.
>         You should check your configuration for typos.
>   Note: there were 277 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
>         You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
>         (using '-keep').
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
>   Note: there were 2 library classes explicitly being kept.
>         You don't need to keep library classes; they are already left unchanged.
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#libraryclass)
>   Note: there were 19 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
>         You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
>   Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to library class members.
>            You probably need to update the library versions.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
>   Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   Thread(Tasks limiter_18): destruction

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `-dontnote android.widget.Space` should mute it, but there is more missing.

Comment: @MartinZeitler well, in one experiment I also added everything in android.widget and the out put was slightly different, but always stops in Space. I solved it by forcing use of R8. Any advice on the current warnings is also appreciated, ProGuard output is very unhelpful. Thanks.